# Coherent usage of Hibernate's session and DAO

Tags: java, hibernate, session, dao

Here is my code

```
public void something()
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.newSession();
    AModelDAO amd = new AModelDAO(session);
    BModelDAO bmd = new BModelDAO(session);

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    amd.savesomething(object);
    bmd.savesomething(object2);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

I would like to know if my coding here is good enough or if there is a better method to produce the same result.

Thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please note that this is not a code review site. You probably want to use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review Perhaps try codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok but you can try use some framework (Spring for example) or application server to automatically manage transactions. 
If you want to try Spring read this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html